# Transparent content in settings windows

Tags: gui, 14.10, system-settings

After reinstalling Ubuntu 14.10 less than a day before, I now have the following issue: The background of the content section of every window in the system settings (except the overview) is transparent. That means of these windows I only see the window bar and the content in the window. I didn't mess around with any Compiz-Stuff. I only installed the nvidia graphics drivers and a few programs and uninstalled some programs I don't need.

Does anyone know how I get the window background back to its original white color?